# pd.ExcelFile to refer to all sheets

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a xlsx file with a number of sheets that I'd like the code to refer to but I can't seem to get this to work

```
xlsx = pd.ExcelFile('Path to xlsx file')
xlsx.sheet_names
df1 = pd.read_excel('file name.xlsx', sheet_name='name')
df2 = pd.read_excel('file name.xlsx', sheet_name='name')
df3 = pd.read_excel('file name.xlsx', sheet_name='name')
df4 = pd.read_excel('file name.xlsx', sheet_name='name')
df5 = pd.read_excel('file name.xlsx', sheet_name='name')
```

I'm still pretty new to Pandas and Python so sorry if this seems like a silly question. I've also already read the documentation but can't seem to figure it out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: to get a clear understanding: do you want to read all the sheets from an excel file??

Comment: @SubbuVidyaSekar Yes please, I'm hoping the code I've written will execute for each sheet listed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list of dataframes.

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile('Path to xlsx file')
dfs=[]
for sheet in xls.sheet_names:
    dfs.append(pd.read_excel('Path to xlsx file',sheet_name=sheet))

print(dfs[0])
print(dfs[1])
```

**EDIT**

A great solution would be to use dict, if you know the name of the sheets, you can call whatever df you like.

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile('Path to xlsx file')
dfs={}
for sheet in xls.sheet_names:
    dfs[sheet] = pd.read_excel('Path to xlsx file',sheet_name=sheet)

print(dfs['put the name of sheet you want to use'])
```

Comment: Hi thanks for a solution. So the goal is to read all the sheets within the excel file and have the code I've written execute for each sheet. Is that possible with the dictionary method?

Comment: Of course, if the code is the same for all the dfs use "for df in dfs.values():", otherwise use the sheet name to call the df and do what you want with it, example: dfs['sheet1'].

Comment: I'm still a little confused on how to get this to work, I've created a new question for this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70035100/using-pd-excelfile-and-running-the-code-through-each-sheet). Would you please be able to help me there and provide a solution in the answers?

Comment: Also, when I use the dictionary method for the list of sheets, I get a 'TypeError: 'set' object does not support item assignment'