# Using pd.ExcelFile and running the code through each sheet

Tags: python, pandas

I wrote this code to calculate some simple bonus pays and the excel file I've been given has 7 sheets for each day of the week. Is it possible to use `pd.ExcelFile` to apply the code through all 7 sheets?

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.ExcelFile('filepath.xlsx')
dfs = {
 '25.10'
 '26.10'
 '27.10'
 '28.10'
 '29.10'
 '30.10'
 '31.10'
}
for sheet in xlsx.sheet_names:
    dfs['25.10'] = df.read_excel('filepath'.xlsx', sheet_name= '25.10')

df['T1 Finish'] = pd.to_datetime(df['T1 Finish'].astype(str))

df['T1 Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['T1 Start'].astype(str))

df['Hours'] = (df['T1 Finish'] - df['T1 Start']).dt.total_seconds() /3600

df['Average Parcels'] = df['T1 Delivered']/df['Hours']

df['Incentive'] = df['Average Parcels'].mul(1.4).where(df['Average Parcels'].between(10, 18, "left"),0)

per_day = df.groupby(['Date', 'Rider']).agg(sum)

per_courier = df.groupby(['Rider']).agg(sum)

with pd.ExcelWriter('filepath/newfile.xlsx', mode='a') as writer:
     per_day.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Per Day')
     per_courier.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Per Courier')
```

So ideally, the end product will be the original sheets and it's calculations and then 2 new sheets called 'Per Day' and 'Per Courier' where all the calculations are aggregated.

I've managed to execute this code successfully for the first sheet but not the other 6.

I'm still new to Pandas and Python, thanks in advance.

Example Data:

```
data = {'Date': ['25/10/21', '25/10/21', '25/10/21', '25/10/21', '25/10/21'],
      'ID': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
      'T1 Start': ['10:45:00', '11:25:00', '10:13:00', '13:20:00', '11:35:00'],
      'T1 Finish': ['19:20:00', '14:48:00', '13:18:00', '16:32:00', '17:00:00']
      'T1 Delivered': [52, 35, 35, 26, 36]
  }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: In which df do you want to make this piece of code run? All? So concatenate?

df['T1 Finish'] = pd.to_datetime(df['T1 Finish'].astype(str))

df['T1 Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['T1 Start'].astype(str))

df['Hours'] = (df['T1 Finish'] - df['T1 Start']).dt.total_seconds() /3600

df['Average Parcels'] = df['T1 Delivered']/df['Hours']

df['Incentive'] = df['Average Parcels'].mul(1.4).where(df['Average Parcels'].between(10, 18, "left"),0)

Comment: Edit the post with a piece of the table on "25.10", please.

Comment: So in the 1 excel file there are 7 sheets representing each day of the week. I need this code to calculate and work for all 7 sheets.

Comment: Okay, with a piece of dataframe on first sheet i can help you better.

Comment: @Wilian Added some example data at the bottom, hope that helps and thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd

path = 'filepath.xlsx'

xls = pd.ExcelFile(path)
dfs={}
for sheet in xls.sheet_names:
    dfs[sheet] = pd.read_excel(path ,sheet_name=sheet)
    

df = pd.concat(dfs).reset_index(drop=True)

df['T1 Finish'] = pd.to_datetime(df['T1 Finish'].astype(str))

df['T1 Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['T1 Start'].astype(str))

df['Hours'] = (df['T1 Finish'] - df['T1 Start']).dt.total_seconds() /3600

df['Average Parcels'] = df['T1 Delivered']/df['Hours']

df['Incentive'] = df['Average Parcels'].mul(1.4).where(df['Average Parcels'].between(10, 18, "left"),0)

### TAKE A LOOK AT THE CODE BELOW, I DONT KNOW WHERE THE COLUMN 'Rider' IS.

per_day = df.groupby(['Date', 'Rider']).agg(sum)
per_courier = df.groupby(['Rider']).agg(sum)


book = load_workbook(path)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine = 'openpyxl')
writer.book = book

per_day.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Per Day')
per_courier.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Per Courier')

writer.save()
writer.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and everything works now. But is it possible to have the original data printed as well alongside 'Per Day' and 'Per Courier'? It's just so we can validate the data in the same workbook.

Comment: The original data from 7 sheets were combined and returned into 'Sheet 1' when I added this line `df.to_excel(new file path, header=True)`. Could you let me know if this is the best way to do it? Thanks again for your help

Comment: There are some possibilities as to leaving two or more dataframes on the same sheet. Is that what you want?

Comment: I think leaving the raw data (without groupby) in a separate sheet is the most appropriate. This I believe you have already achieved.

Comment: I had some issues with opening the data after running the code. Removing `writer.save()` worked for me. Not sure why that is but thank you anyway Wilian! I appreciate all your help.